# How to use Copyleaks API in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, copyleaks-api

I would to know how to use Copyleaks API in Tkinter as I am developing plagiarism checker using Tkinter.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is too broad, please see the [How to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find tips about how to improve it. Please share some code showing what you have tried. As it is, your question sounds like you are either seeking tutorial/library recommendations, which is off-topic, or that you are asking people to write the code for you which is not StackOverflow's purpose either.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.